# How to change detail of snippet in sublime text 3

Tags: ajax, angularjs, sublimetext3

I use snippet easy to input to , however , some snippet has an outdate detail.
such as  snippet  of  Google ajax of Angular as  following..

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com /ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.js
```

recently angular has v. 1.2.26 . Where I can go to edit from source.? since I have to edit each time to call snippet.

Comment: What is the name of the Angular package you are using? There are several.

Comment: try in:

Preferences -> Package Settings -> [the_package_you_wanna_change]